# The facebook comment code is not working

Tags: facebook, comments

The facebook comment code is not working.
I want to use facebook comment code... i get the code from

```
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/comments/
```

but its not working...
 2 days before i used this code and it was working fyn.. but today its not working..I dont know why..plz help.. here is waht i copied from above link

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
 var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
<div class="fb-comments" data-href="http://example.com/comments" data-colorscheme="The     color scheme used in the plugin" data-numposts="5" data-width="The pixel width of the plugin"></div>
```

Comment: The generators don’t seem to set default values correctly atm – go place the correct values here `data-colorscheme="The color scheme used in the plugin"` and here `data-width="The pixel width of the plugin"` yourself (or leave those parameters out completely).

Comment: i leave those parameters but still its not working

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No my dear the comment section on facebook is down the problem is from facebook not from you

sit down relax and they will fix it soon it's a common problem

Khodor

Answer (score 0):

are you using Chrome ?

if yes then your AdBlock or Disconnect Extension is making problem.